# Use Biblatex to get an overview of the keywords from my sources

Tags: latex, keyword, bibliography, biblatex

Hi I'm using LaTeX to write a literature review and BibLaTeX to print my sources and bibliography.

**I would like to get an overview of all the keywords used in the articles I have gathered so far.**

Since I have them all in a .bib file I figured that there probably is some easy way to get all the keywords from there that utilises BibLaTeX and the BibTeX-format of the file with the info.

From what I can gather BibLaTeX has the support for using keywords to sort the bibliography, or include/exclude certain sources based on keywords, but I can't find if or how I can print other information from the .bib than the full source. I've found \printfield in the documentation but it's not recognised when I use it in my document, even though the \textcite and the \printbibliography works fine so I'm guessing I'm using it wrong. Here's how I've tried to use it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Citation examples}
\parencite{Smith:2012qr}.
\printfield{keywords}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I hope my question is clear enough.
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332292/listing-indexing-and-linking-keywords-in-biblatex you could use one of the packages for index creation, e.g. `imakeidx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Padial2010,
        title={The Integrative Future Of Taxonomy},
        author={Padial, J.M. and Miralles, A. and la Riva, I.D. and Vences, M.},
        journal={Frontiers in Zoology},
        year={2010},
        volume={7},
        number={16},
        pages={1--14},
        note={Cited by 4},
        abstract={Text},
        publisher={Some Publishing},
        doi={10.1186/1742-9994-7-16},
        issn={1742-9994},
        file={./2004_Jensen_Homecoming.pdf},
        keywords={biology, taxonomy},
    }
    
        @article{Padissal2010,
            title={The Integrative Future Of Taxonomy},
            author={Padial, J.M. and Miralles, A. and la Riva, I.D. and Vences, M.},
            journal={Frontiers in Zoology},
            year={2010},
            volume={7},
            number={16},
            pages={1--14},
            note={Cited by 4},
            abstract={Text},
            publisher={Some Publishing},
            doi={10.1186/1742-9994-7-16},
            issn={1742-9994},
            file={./2004_Jensen_Homecoming.pdf},
            keywords={math, taxonomy},
        }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=keywords, title=List of Keywords]
\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{keywords}{\forcsvfield{\index[keywords]}{keywords}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\indexfield{keywords}}


\begin{document}
    \nocite{*} 
    \printbibliography
    
    \printindex[keywords]
\end{document}
```

[image]